# How to avoid recursive and multiple include directive in JSP?

Tags: jsp, include

I have 4 jsp files and 1 js file: `index.jsp`, `connect.jsp`, `load1.jsp`, `load2.jsp`, and `function.js`. Please see codes below to understand the relationship between them.
index.jsp

```
<%@include file = "load1.jsp" %>
<%@include file = "load2.jsp" %>
```

connect.jsp

```
<%!
    public String makeConnection(){
        String str = "connect to database";
        return str;
    }
%>
```

load1.jsp

```
<%@include file = "connect.jsp" %>
<%
    out.print(makeConnection());
%>
<button onclick = "doXHR()">load2</button>
```

load2.jsp

```
<%@include file = "connect.jsp" %>
<%
    out.print(makeConnection());
%>
```

function.js

```
function doXHR(){
    ...
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "load2.jsp", true);
    ...
}
```

Please note that those codes are not actual code since I have to make it simpler so I can post them here. The problem is when I go to `index.jsp`, there will be error like `makeConnection() is already defined`.
If I remove this line `<%@include file = "connect.jsp" %>` from `load2.jsp`, it will work but if then I click the button, it will give 500 status code and its error is like `cannot find symbol: method makeConnection()`.
How can I solve this? Thanks!